# How to replace instances of a char by ints, then access an array with them

Tags: c++, string, replace, parameter-passing, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to call this function on a string and pass in a 3d char array.

The function should replace all instances of 'u' in the word with '0', 'c' with '1,' etc...

Then I want it to reference the array cell associated with the string.

i.e. - if 'word' was 'gcu' it should become 310 and then access Array[3][1][0].

```
char whatitbe(std::string word, char Array[][][])

{
replace(word.begin(), word.end(), 'u', '0');
replace(word.begin(), word.end(), 'c', '1');
replace(word.begin(), word.end(), 'a', '2');
replace(word.begin(), word.end(), 'g', '3');

int a, b, c;
stringstream ss;
ss << word;
ss >> a >> b >> c;

char temp = Array[a][b][c];
return temp;
```

};

workup.cpp:32:10: error: 'word' was not declared in this scope

workup.cpp:42:14: error: 'Array' was not declared in this scope

Why???

Comment: Woah, 3D array. At least make one dimension into a string. Are those the only errors you get? Nothing about unknown bounds?

Answer (score 3):

```
char Array[][][]
```

You have to specify the 2nd and 3rd dimension of the `Array`.

For example:

```
char Array[][2][2]; //exact value depends on your application
```